# Backbone Design - Multiple Views, Same Model, separation of events

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, backbone.js

I am quite experienced with JS and Backbone, but want your help brainstorming a best practise solution to the following problem:

There are two views. They sit side-by-side running concurrently in the page.
Both of these views are passed the same instance of a model.
Both of these views have actions which can update the model.

How, using Backbone's event driven programming, do you think would be the best way of distinguishing the events fired from view to view.

A possible scenario could be:
The user performs an action which updates the model in an invalid way on View A. But as the user did not perform it on View B they should not be notified there.

Comment: Got any feedback for the answers provided?

Answer (score 0):

You can use intermediary objects to manage the flow between a repository (the object where the connection to the database takes place) and the instantiation / manipulation of views.
Instead of binding a model to a view from within the view, you can let the intermediary object (general purpose controller) make verifications, if required manipulations, before re-rendering the view with the modified model or collection.
Through the use of an event aggregator, you can trigger events from views from within the view, and listen to the event from within the "controller" object, who will in turn perform the required custom actions.

Answer (score 0):

Using custom events seems simple enough. Just treat each view's actions as if they were different and name the events differently for each view (example this.trigger('view1:event1'), this.trigger('view2:event2')).

Make sure the views are subscribed to these specific custom events to avoid collisions on actions that would trigger events on both views (like attribute updates).